# nginx HTTP Error 500 when retrieving 1 Million rows

Tags: php, postgresql, nginx, laravel, laravel-4

Using nginx 1.7 & PHP (Laravel framework) to retrieve 1+ million rows from a PostgreSQL database causes the error 500 to be displayed within 10 seconds.

`HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.`

I've already set some timeouts to be longer and reloaded nginx but its not working. Which settings will prevent this timeout?

**sites-enabled**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 6000;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 6000;
    client_body_timeout 6000;
    send_timeout 6000;
    proxy_read_timeout 6000;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the timeout is in `nginx`, and not in PostgreSQL or FastCGI? NginX should give you a 504 error, not a 500 error. Try loading the same page without NginX and see what happens. However, also check out the `client_header_timeout` directive, just in case.

Comment: I am able to retrieve all 1M rows from PostgreSQL using pgAdmin3 software, so PostgreSQL isnt the one timing out. Set `client_header_timeout 6000` and I still get the same error 500. How should I adjust FastCGI timeouts?

Comment: pgAdmin3 will very likely process those lines differently from Laravel. Can you access the Laravel page bypassing `nginx`? Anyway, see tentative answer below for possible clues and ways of proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain my somewhat cryptic comment, and supply a possible answer:

This **does not look like a timeout**, which should make `nginx` issue a `504 Gateway Timeout` error. HTTP Error 500 means there was actually an *error*, i.e.:

- PHP (Laravel) went out of memory
- The PostgreSQL connection was aborted
- The FastCGI process gave up the ghost

So you have three places where to check: the fastcgi logs, the Laravel/PHP error log, and possibly PostgreSQL (not very likely, since PostgreSQL should not have issues dealing with millions of rows - but maybe there are memory issues).

Directly loading the page, without passing from `nginx`, ought to give a more informative error anyway, if you don't want to, or can't, check the logs.

My money would be on a memory error in the PHP layer, or failing that, on a resource (memory and/or CPU) exhaustion issue in the FastCGI.

If that is so, you can probably quickly solve the issue by allowing a higher memory footprint to PHP processes in `php.ini`; or better, redesign the process so that it doesn't take in so much data (you surely don't display one million rows; maybe you're doing in PHP some processing that could be better done at the PostgreSQL level?).

Comment: Turns out to be a PHP memory issue. Increasing to 2GB helps. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have been of use, but please keep in mind the last paragraph - there's almost surely bound to be a faster and/or less memory intensive way of doing whatever you're doing. I have found myself in the same straits more than once, and PostgreSQL has lots of support for crunching data - much better and more efficient than PHP. (You might maybe ask another question on that topic, or on **dba**)

Comment: Yes I agree with you, I've just migrated from MySQL to PostgreSQL and will eventually do the number crunching in PostgreSQL. Add the moment I'm retrieving all the rows from PostgreSQL and enqueueing them into a job queue (beanstalkd)

Comment: Doing this kind of work via an ORM is usually a terrible idea; if possible, use ordinary native queries to iteratively fetch and process the data. You can use cursors so you don't need to fit much of it in memory at a time.